# PostgresException: 3D000: database "kap_dev" does not exist

Tags: npgsql, serenity-platform

I am using [serenity](https://serenity.is/docs/postgresql) with postgres and I have generated a new project using visual studio 2019.

I have followed the tutorial of how to make the app connect with Postgresql.

I have created a new database and user in PgAdmin.

I have enabled the app to run migrations when I run my app.

Here is a sample of my connection string.

```
  "Data": {
"Default": {
  "ConnectionString": "Server=localhost;  Port=5432;    User Id=kap_dev;  Database=kap_db;  Password=kapap_password;",
  "ProviderName": "Npgsql"
}
```

However, I get the error

> PostgresException: 3D000: database "kap_dev" does not exist.

The issue is that kap_dev is a user and not a database.

I even posted this error to their git-issues but serenity have not responded with a valid answer.

Comment: How about spaces and order of connectionstring parts? Serenity doesn't interest with connection string parts. It's used by postgresql related nuget package directly. Serenity just pass this connection string to defined database provider. 

Check this https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/

Comment: Also you can try new console application with pgsql and ensure about everything is ok with that connection string.

Comment: @VictorTomaili I have referred to the link you shared, I used the Npgsql package and I did re order the items in the connection string but that was not the solution.

Comment: I used latest serenity with postgresql 2 weeks before. And it's works perfect. Your postgresql installation or configuration may has problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try running migration first before running the project. The database should be created !

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34881133)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

might be a typo, no space between User and Id

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the solution. I have removed the space and also re ordered the items in the connection string but I get the same error.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a database which name is the name of your user "kap_dev".

Comment: I have tried creating the database and the user has super-user rights. Please note, kap_dev is a database user not the database.

Comment: The message is clear : "database "kap_dev" does not exist". The default database name for connexion is the same as the user name. In your case the user is not postgres but "kap_dev".

Comment: The DB is configured as per the connection string. So kindly try replicating the error from your end. I'd be grateful for that